# Data view: Subscribers - Ask for Optin

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, journeybuilder, servicecloud

my data for AbandonedCart comes as CSV via File drop. The data contains amongst other fields Email and Optin. The Optin can be delivered as True and False. I will send the people with TRUE an AbandonedCart Email. I now want to check if the people that have Optin = False are existing customers or subscribers that I'm allowed to send an email.

I have a Master Data Ext merged over data stream with data from Lead_Salesforce and Account_Salesforce. The Optin status is in there.

Data Table `ABANDONED_CART_SHOP_DATA` contains

```
EmailAdress, Optin, AbandonDate, Firstname, Lastname, ...Product Data
```

Master Data Table contains
`EmailAdress, Optin, Firstname, Lastname, Lead_ID, Account_ID, Salesforce_ID` (which is either `Lead_ID` or `Account_ID`)

In Contact Builder I have the following relationships

[image][image]

Is the use of a query on Data view: Subscribers a way to go here or what is your suggestion?

Thanks!
Oliver

Problem resolved. My Query to join both tables

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   
ENT.ABANDONED_CART_SHOP_DATA a

LEFT JOIN 
ENT.MASTER_DATA_ACCOUNT m 

ON 
a.EmailAddress = m.EmailAddress

WHERE 
a.OptIn = 'true' 
OR m.Email_Optin = 1
```

Target DE triggers the journey.

Comment: Please could you provide details of the AbandonedCart data extension you are importing to? Do you have the CRM LeadID or AccountID available as fields?

Comment: Are you using Person Accounts in SFDC? Can both leads and PersonAccounts abandon their carts?

Comment: Yes. I use Person Accounts and both can abandon. At time of upload the CSV I only have the email as an identifier to check if the person is a lead or an account with optin=true.